# Can't Access 2+ Child of Databound Pivot

Tags: windows-phone-7

Ok, this is my first post here, so I'm not sure how detailed I need to be and I'm not the best at describing things, but I'll give it a shot.

So on the main page of my App, when a user click on a textblock it sends them to the next page which is a dynamic pivot page:

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent" DataContext="{Binding Products}">
    <!--Pivot Control-->
    <controls:Pivot x:Name="Pivot" Title="{Binding name}" ItemsSource="{Binding pivots}">
        <controls:Pivot.HeaderTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding title}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </controls:Pivot.HeaderTemplate>
        <controls:Pivot.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ListBox Margin="0,0,-12,0" ItemsSource="{Binding partners}">
                    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Margin="0,0,0,17" Width="432" Height="58">
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding name}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Tap="showDetails" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextExtraLargeStyle}"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                </ListBox>
            </DataTemplate>
        </controls:Pivot.ItemTemplate>
    </controls:Pivot>
</Grid>
```

It passes a parameter that specifies what DataContext should be used on the page, and which pivot should be selected. OnNavigation, it then parse those parameters:

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e) {
        base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
        string selectedType = this.NavigationContext.QueryString["type"];
        string selectedPivot = this.NavigationContext.QueryString["pivot"];
        int selectedIndex = 0;
        switch (selectedType) {
            case "product":
                LayoutRoot.DataContext = App.ViewModel.Products;
                selectedIndex = Array.IndexOf(App.ViewModel.ProductTypes, selectedPivot);
                break;
            case "service":
                LayoutRoot.DataContext = App.ViewModel.Services;
                selectedIndex = Array.IndexOf(App.ViewModel.ServiceTypes, selectedPivot);
                break;
            default:
                LayoutRoot.DataContext = App.ViewModel.Products;
                break;
        }
        Pivot.SelectedIndex = selectedIndex;
        PivotItem pivotItem = Pivot.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(Pivot.SelectedItem) as PivotItem;
        this.selectedList = FindFirstElementInVisualTree<ListBox>(pivotItem);
}
```

The [FindFirstElementInVisualTree](http://windowsphonegeek.com/tips/how-to-access-a-control-placed-inside-listbox-itemtemplate-in-wp7) is from [here](http://windowsphonegeek.com/tips/how-to-access-a-control-placed-inside-listbox-itemtemplate-in-wp7)

**So here's my problem:**
This all works fine when I select the first dataset and the first pivot, otherwise it says that pivotItem doesn't have any children and throws an error.

Any Idea's what I can do to get around this? Maybe I'm going about this all wrong. If you need more details, just let me know.

Answer (score 0):

The Pivot control delay-loads the PivotItemss until they are actually needed - it only loads the current PivotItem and the one before and after it.  When the user navigates to the next PivotItem, then you'll see the PivotItem created.

This also manifests itself when trying to restore the user to the previous PivotItem after tombstoning - it falls over if trying to restore to the third pivot item as described [here](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/604360/unhandled-exception-when-setting-pivot-control-selecteditem-selectedindex-property-to-3rd-pivot-item-wp7).

Comment: Read through the post. I don't seem to be having the problem that was mentioned. I can select the PivotItems other than the next a previous.

I looked at the work around, but I couldn't see how it applied.